# D7 Panelizer: Right sidebar blocks not displaying

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Right sidebar content blocks are not showing up with Drupal 7 [panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer). 
I have activated the blocks in the panelizer settings but when I save, they still aren't displaying. Here are some screenshots:
[image: Panelizer settings]

[image: Page output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, follow these steps:

1. Flush drupal cache
2. Make sure you have content in those blocks.
3. Inspect the region sidebar using the browser to make sure that the region is been rendered.